# Что с этим делать inline_handler()

Tags: python, aiogram

Код выдает такую ошибку: aiogram.utils.exceptions.InvalidQueryID: Query is too old and response timeout expired or query id is invalid

```
@dp.inline_handler()
async def inline_query_handler(query: types.InlineQuery):
        query_offset = int(query.offset) if query.offset else 1
        search_query = query.query.strip().lower()  
        film_results = film_all()

        filtered_results = [film for film in film_results if search_query in film[1].lower()]

        chunk_size = 50
        results = [
            types.InlineQueryResultArticle(
                id=film[0], 
                title=film[1],
                input_message_content=types.InputTextMessageContent(message_text=f'/get_{film[0]}'),
                description=film[2],
                thumb_url=('https:' + film[3]) if film[3].startswith('//') else film[3]
            )
            for film in filtered_results[(query_offset-1)*chunk_size:query_offset*chunk_size]
        ]

        next_offset = query_offset + 1 if len(filtered_results) > query_offset * chunk_size else ""
        
        await query.answer(results, is_personal=True, next_offset=str(next_offset))
```